# Complete subsets of pseudometric spaces

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces

A subset $E$ of a metric space $X$ is called **complete** if every Cauchy sequence of points in $E$ is convergent and has its limit in $E$.

How should complete subsets be defined in a non-Hausdorff psuedometric space, where limits are not unique?

Should it be:

1. A subset $E$ of a pseudometric space $X$ is called **complete** if every Cauchy sequence of points in $E$ is convergent and has *all* of its limits in $E$.
2. A subset $E$ of a pseudometric space $X$ is called **complete** if every Cauchy sequence of points in $E$ is convergent and has *at least one* of its limits in $E$.

Is one of these the standard definition? Is there a third definition that is actually the standard?

Note:

1. has the advantage that complete subsets are closed.
2. has the advantage that a subset $E$ of $X$ is complete if and only if $E$ is complete when viewed as a pseudometric space (with the pseudometric inherited from $X$).

Comment: It depends on your objective. The easiest thing to do is to require the metric quotient of your pseudometric space to be complete.

Comment: @MoisheKohan Why is that the easiest? Is that approach equivalent to either of the definitions I proposed?

Comment: It depends on the context, some of which can be seen [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Complete_topological_space).

Answer (score 1):

A subset $E$ is seen as a pseudometric space in its own right (with the restricted pseudometric), so a Cauchy sequence in $E$ should have **a** limit in $E$. It need not be unique. This adheres to the usual convention of e.g. Cauchy nets in uniform spaces as well.